# Проблема с загрузкой двумерного вектора из файла

Tags: c++, консоль, вектор

Мой код должен загрузить двумерный вектор(`void loadVector()`) 4х4 из файла с названием vector.txt из своего каталога и вывести его в консоль, однако он криво загружается по неизвестной мне причине. Скорее всего, я использую неправильную функцию (мне нужно получать, желательно, символы вместо строк). Может, есть более хороший способ хранения больших двумерных векторов?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int WIDTH = 4, HEIGHT = 4;
vector<vector<char>> a(WIDTH, vector<char>(HEIGHT));


void genVector() {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); ++j) {
            a[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }
}


void showVector() {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
            cout << a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


void saveVector() {
    ofstream fout("BigVector/vector.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); ++j) {
            fout << a[i][j];
        }
        fout << endl;
    }
    
    fout.close();
}

//Проблема здесь
void loadVector() {
    ifstream fin("BigVector/vector.txt");

    int bSize = WIDTH;
    char buff[bSize]; 

    //А именно в этом цикле
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); ++j) {
            fin.getline(buff, bSize);
            a[i][j] = buff[j];
        }
    }
/* оно получает
200
 00
 00
 00
*/
/* должно получить
2000
0300
0010
0004
*/
    fin.close();
}


int main()
{
    loadVector();
    showVector();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Вместо getline я использую, видимо, по-символьный ввод в временную перемену buff и вставляю в вектор

```
void loadVector() {
    ifstream fin("BigVector/vector.txt"); //открываю файл(можно и не .txt формат, а свой(к примеру у себя я назвал его .save), откуда будет читаться вектор
    char buff; //временная переменная
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) { //проход по строкам
        for(int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); ++j) { //проход по символам в строке
            fin >> buff; //по-символьный ввод в переменную buff
            a[i][j] = buff; //установка значения из buff в сам вектор
        }

    }
    fin.close(); //закрытие файла
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

У тебя здесь функция `getline` вызывается `i * j` раз. Нужно переписать следующим образом:

```
void loadVector() {
  ifstream fin("BigVector/vector.txt");

  int bSize = WIDTH;
  char buff[bSize]; 

  
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
      fin.getline(buff, bSize);
      for (int j = 0; j < bSize; ++j) {
          a[i][j] = buff[j];
      }
  }
  fin.close();
}
```

Еще несколько замечаний по коду:

```
vector<vector<char>> a(WIDTH, vector<char>(HEIGHT))
```

Перепутаны местами `WIDTH` и `HEIGHT`. Ты выделяешь `WIDTH` ячеек, а затем говоришь, что в каждой ячейке должен лежать вектор длины `HEIGHT`.

Во вложенном цикле неправильны установлены границы индексов. Правильно написать:

```
void showVector() {
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++) {
      cout << a[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Почему? Дело в том, что `a.size()` - количество ячеек, а `a[i].size()` - размер ячейки.

Использовать 'using namespace std' плохая практика. Почитать об этом можно здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Благодарю тебя за ответ. Насчет using - я просто хотел посмотреть, как можно сохранять, загружать вектора из .txt формата

Comment: М, нет. Тот же самый результат. Может, он читает одну и ту же строку?